# What is the correct transcription of 'wikinames'?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, ipa

I thought that this is `[ˌwiki'neimz]`, but do I really need to indicate primary stress, since `names` contains only one syllable?

Comment: The first syllable is /wɪk/, isn't it? And I'd put the stress on the first syllable, which shows that you really do need to indicate the primary stress since it isn't obvious.

Comment: Ah, thanks, @PeterShor. Could you please post it as the answer, so I will be able to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I pronounce *wikinames* is /'wɪkiˌneimz/, where the first syllable has the same vowel as *wick* and is stressed.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. How do you pronounce Wikipedia? The dictionary I use says it should be `[ˌwɪkɪˈpiːdɪə]`

Comment: The dictionary is correct. I can't find an official pronunciation for *wikinames* anywhere, but I am fairly sure that my pronunciation is reasonably widespread.